# Como fazer um mapeamento dos retornos de um Store Procedure para as propriedades de uma classe?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dapper

ViewModel

```
  public class ClienteResult
{

    [Display(Name ="intParc_Cod")]
    public int ClienteId { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public string CPF { get; set; }

    public decimal Saldo { get; set; }

}
```

Repositorio  (Dapper)

```
    public IEnumerable<ClienteResult> SaldoCliente(int id)
    {
    return
            _context
            .Connection
            .Query<ClienteResult>(
            "EXEC sp_cliente_saldo @Id", new {Id = id } );
    }
```

Controller

```
    [HttpGet("v1/cliente/saldocliente/{id:int}")]
    public  IActionResult SaldoCliente(int id)
    {
        return Ok(_repository.SaldoCliente(id));
    }
```

Boa tarde,

Tenho um serviço (Web Api) que possui uma classe (ou ViewModel) que retorna o cliente e o seu saldo. Obtenho este dado através de uma execução de uma procedure e depois chamo em um controller que resulta o JSON.

Bom, o problema é que para eu retornar o JSON com seus respectivos valores a minha classe ClienteResult todos os seus campos tem que ser igual ao que está na tabela do banco de dados.
Eu queria retornar com está na classe (ex.:ClienteId, Nome) e não como a procedure retorna (codigo_cli, nome_cli).

Já tentei o Data Annotation [Column("codigo_cli"]] e o [Display(Name="ClienteId")], mas não deu certo.

Existe alguma outra alternativa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A resposta é mais ou menos o que você tentou, mas o `display` é usado na exibição de formulários. O que você está procurando é o `JsonProperty` , exemplo

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "intParc_Cod")]
public int ClienteId { get; set; }
```

Comment: Deu certo, ficou legal. Mas acabei usando [DataContract] e [DataMember]